# Can the word "thoughts" be used as singular?

Tags: vocabulary, grammatical-number

I was watching BBC the other day and heard the news presenter Sally Bundock ask somebody

"What's your thoughts on immigration?"

I am confused as to how "thoughts" which until now I took as a plural word can be used as a singular word. Is this usage common in English speaking countries? And are there any other similar words which are used thus?

Answer (score 1):

I think that **what's** should really be **what are** because *thoughts* after all is a plural word. The world has not gone crazy. Grammar is grammar and you can't escape it. But, in conversational English, native speakers quite often use *what's* even for plural things. For example, I once heard Jerry Seinfeld, one of the four main characters in the American sitcom [Seinfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seinfeld), say:

> Where's my shoes?

He obviously should have said "*where are my shoes?*" because *shoes* is plural. But, as I already said, in daily English using *what's* instead of *what are* (or *where's* instead of *where are*) is possible and you will see native speakers do that quite often.

I guess, one reason this happens has probably to do with the fact that *what's* is easier and faster to pronounce than *what are*. This is very similar to the situation with *there's*. When you are talking about something that's more than one in quantity, you should say *there are*, but in conversational English, almost everyone says *there's*. I'm quite sure you know this.